# How to set export PATH="$HOME/neovim/bin:$PATH" automatically

Tags: neovim

I'm on a Raspberry Pi 5 and I had to build from source to get the latest stable version. The program built successfully and I'm able to run it just fine. However whenever I open a new terminal I have to run the command `export PATH="$HOME/neovim/bin:$PATH"`before I can use the program as normal. How can I set my terminal to automatically run this command when I open it, without having to type it in manually. Please explain it as if I'm a completely new user. Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: Welcome to Vi and Vim SE. Your question is about your shell, not about (Neo)Vim. I voted to close as off-topic. As to your question, you're probably using Bash so there should be a file (create it if it does not exist) `~/.bashrc` where you can put your `export` statement in. Also see `man bash` or [Unix and Linux SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com).